# While loop doesn't stop after boolean condition is no longer true

Tags: c#, arrays, matrix, while-loop, boolean

In this while loop I'm examining that if the word that I'm trying to put into the matrix can fit in or not.

It checks if the `matrix[i]` is empty or white-space, or is the same character as the `word[i]`.

My problem is that the while loop doesn't stop when it comes to a place where the characters don't match or the `matrix[i]` is not empty. With the `Console.WriteLine` I wrote out the characters to see what can be the problem.

```
private bool Crossing(string word, int _row, int _col, int x, int y)
{
    int i = 0;
    bool l;
    bool crossing = ((matrix[(i * x) + _row, (i * y) + _col] == word[i]) || (matrix[(i * x) + _row, (i * y) + _col] == ' '));
    while(i < word.Length && crossing)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(i + ". char in matrix: " + matrix[(i * x) + _row, (i * y) + _col]);
        Console.WriteLine("i + ". char in word: " + word[i]);
        i++;
    }
    l = i >= word.Length;
    Console.WriteLine(l);
    return l;
}
```

Comment: Since the `crossing` variable is also dependent on the value of `i`, shouldn't it be moved inside the loop ?

Answer (score 1):

Probably you need to put the setting of the boolean variable `crossing` inside the loop otherwise the only way to exit from that loop is when i reaches the `word` length

```
private bool Crossing(string word, int _row, int _col, int x, int y)
{
    int i = 0;
    bool l;
    bool crossing = true;        
    while(i < word.Length && crossing)
    {

        Console.WriteLine(i + ". char in matrix: " + matrix[(i * x) + _row, (i * y) + _col]);
        Console.WriteLine("i + ". char in word: " + word[i]);
        crossing = ((matrix[(i * x) + _row, (i * y) + _col] == word[i]) || (matrix[(i * x) + _row, (i * y) + _col] == ' '));

        i++;
    }
    l = i >= word.Length;
    Console.WriteLine(l);
    return l;
}
```

Comment: I moved the crossing variable to the loop, but when it comes to the last characters, and still returns as `True`.

Comment: What is the content of the variable _matrix_ ? What are the values of the variables _word, _row, _col, x and y_ As usual this kind of problems are easily resolved using the debugger and following step by step what happens in the loop. However, if you give us working data we could test it

Comment: I just made `l = i >= word.Length && crossing ` and now it's working like a charm. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

You are not refreshing `crossing` variable:

```
while(i < word.Length && crossing)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(i + ". char in matrix: " + matrix[(i * x) + _row, (i * y) + _col]);
        Console.WriteLine("i + ". char in word: " + word[i]);
        i++;

        crossing = ((matrix[(i * x) + _row, (i * y) + _col] == word[i]) || (matrix[(i * x) + _row, (i * y) + _col] == ' '));
    }
```